# unbinding a view from a model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

This jsfiddle ( http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/avo5nnus/39/ ) demonstrates the problem I'm having, but I will explain here. I have a main view that has a `startInterval` and `stopInterval` function. In the startInterval, I call a method that adds values to a stats array inside a model that I create in the `startInterval` function with code `this.model = new myModel()`. If I stop and then `startInterval` again (at which point the code runs again `this.model = new myModel()`, it's still the same array from the first press of the `startInterval` button.

For example, if I press start, and the random number 3 gets added to the stats array (in the `addToModel` function), and then press stop, and then press start again which adds a 5 to the stats array, the array will actually have a 3, and a 5. You can see the values print to the screen in the jsfiddle if you press start and stop.

In my real application, I've tried to do things like setting the stats array to `[]` but i can't clear it. Ideally I wish to dereference the view from the model.

```
startInterval: function(){

    this.model = new myModel();
    this.model.intervalId =            setInterval(this.addToModel.bind(this), 1000);

},

stopInterval: function(){

    clearInterval(this.model.intervalId);
    var modelstats = this.model.get("stats");


},
addToModel: function(){
    var arr = this.model.get("stats");
    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    var view = new StatView({model: this.model});  

    arr.push(num);
    this.model.set({"stats" : arr });
}
```

Any ideas on a solution?

Although my code doesn't show it, the model is eventually getting added to a collection and then saved to a database, so if the only solution involves destroying the model please take that into consideration (i.e. is there a way to destroy a model without removing it from a collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your "stats" attributes is shared on the prototype via defaults.
because in javascript arrays and objects are mutable, it references to the same array and doesn't create a new one.
What you can do instead is have the defaults as a function that returns the default  - this way they will be unique per instance

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

  defaults: function () {
    return {        
      stats: [],
      intervalId: ''

    }
  }

});
```